# Scala Spark dataframe filter using multiple column based on available value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to filter a dataframe with the below criteria.

I have 2 columns 4Wheel(Subaru, Toyota, GM, null/empty) and 2Wheel(Yamaha, Harley, Indian, null/empty).

I have to filter on 4Wheel with values (Subaru, Toyota), if 4Wheel contain empty/null then filter on 2Wheel with values (Yamaha, Harley)

I couldn't find this type of filtering in different examples. I am new to spark/scala, so could not get enough idea to implement this.

Thanks,
Barun.

Comment: can you add input data and expected value too with null values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use spark SQL built-in function `when` to check if a column is null or empty, and filter accordingly:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, when}

dataframe.filter(when(col("4Wheel").isNull || col("4Wheel").equalTo(""), 
                   col("2Wheel").isin("Yamaha", "Harley")
                ).otherwise(
                   col("4Wheel").isin("Subaru", "Toyota")
                ))
```

So if you have the following input:

```
+---+------+------+
|id |4Wheel|2Wheel|
+---+------+------+
|1  |Toyota|null  |
|2  |Subaru|null  |
|3  |GM    |null  |
|4  |null  |Yamaha|
|5  |      |Yamaha|
|6  |null  |Harley|
|7  |      |Harley|
|8  |null  |Indian|
|9  |      |Indian|
|10 |null  |null  |
+---+------+------+
```

You get the following filtered ouput:

```
+---+------+------+
|id |4Wheel|2Wheel|
+---+------+------+
|1  |Toyota|null  |
|2  |Subaru|null  |
|4  |null  |Yamaha|
|5  |      |Yamaha|
|6  |null  |Harley|
|7  |      |Harley|
+---+------+------+
```